# Do I need to use using third party to work php mail function in Google Cloud Instance?

Tags: php, email, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

My customer told me to move his website to setup in google cloud instance. I have setup Ubuntu, lamp and domain dns. Everything is working fine except outbound email sending. GCI(Google Cloud Instance) said that they are blocking port 25. I also tested with php.ini file by changing port 465 and 587 but it doesn't work. According to their tutorials, it recommend to use SendGrid, Mailgun and Mailjet.

Do I really need to use  third party services to work only php mail function in Google Cloud Instance? I feel it is wasting resources & money. Is there any option without using third party.

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902676/google-compute-instance-receiving-email), but nobody answered on that.

Comment: just install `postfix` & `dovecot`, in order to provide a local `MTA` ...

Comment: For others reading this question. Do not setup your own email SMTP server. Your emails will either be blocked or become SPAM. Use an email service.

Answer (score 1):

In GCP, email ports like 25, 465, and 587 are blocked by default because of the large amount of abuse these ports are susceptible to. In addition to this, having a trusted third-party provider such as SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet relieves Compute Engine and you from maintaining [IP reputation with your receivers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/). While sending email from blocked ports is not allowed, your instances can still receive email.

Here are the following tutorials to set up [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid), [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun), or [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailjet).